# Manipulate matrix in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

It might be a stupid question, but I couldn't find anything relevant on the internet regarding the next thing.

I have the following matrix in an Excel file:

`ClientCode | ClientDescription | THBCK | THHSM | THOEP 
 Cl0001       MyClient             YES     YES      NO`

*Where *THBCK* etc represents ItemCode.

The next steps are: I import the file in a temp table using the import wizard and I would like to create other custom tables based on that temp table in order to manipulate the information much better.

So, I create a table in which I store information about client code and description (I can select the columns header) which works fine. But when I am trying to create the second custom table I get stuck... the wizard is treating THCBK (which for me means the ItemCode) as being column header which is right taking into consideration the wizard purpose, but it does not helping me.

Is there any way I should do in order to create the 2nd custom table based on the ItemCode but with a different column header description for each?

Thank you

Comment: Are you saying these 2 rows repeat?  You can always read it in giving it your own column headers (col1 col2... coln) and put an ID on it to maintain the order then build your tables off of that table in sql.  (maybe post a small set of the excel source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cross apply` helped me in this situation. I have used `cross apply` and not `UNPIVOT` because the `UNPIVOT` does not include `NULL` values.